# i lost my grass plane?

Tags: materials, shaders, particles

Okay so i was modeling some other stuff so undo has no use anymore but i somehow lost my grass plane? It is still there but it is just invisable? alt + h doesn't do anything?
please help

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: hello please share your file

Comment: How can i do that on here ?

Comment: Use https://blend-exchange.com/ or another platform like workupload

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Ska7vjsZ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Ska7vjsZ/)

Comment: thanks Moon, LOL

I forgot what markdown is

Comment: You just needed to copy the right link   ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unplug the image called *grass material Base Color* from the Alpha, it is a completely black image, so it makes the image completely transparent, plug another one or modify it:

[image]

Comment: ohhhh i see what happened all my white coloring has disapeaered thus it being completely black. Thankyou so much! saved me a bunch of time